# disabling SSL for identityserver3

Tags: ssl, identityserver3

new to using this framework.

I have an OAuth client and I am running IdentityServer3 console app.

I get an error to my client saying SSL is required.

Is there a way to disable the SSL from IdentityServer3 (temporarily) so i can develop/code/test my stuff.

It would be handy as other developers are working on this as well.

I have changed the base-points fro https to http but still SSL required error.

thanks

this is my 'server code':

```
    private static string ServerURL = "http://localhost:44335";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Console.Title = "IdentityServer3";

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .WriteTo.LiterateConsole()
            .CreateLogger();

        var webApp = WebApp.Start(  ServerURL, app =>
        {
            app.UseIdentityServer();
        });

        System.Console.WriteLine("identityserver up and running....");

        while(true)
        {
            var key = System.Console.ReadKey(true);
            if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.B)
            {
                Process.Start(ServerURL + "/core");
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        webApp.Dispose();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set 'RequireSsl' to false on the options class.

see https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/blob/c0f147c4f481fe77244ef4a2d5e006a4a4366c41/source/Simplest%20OAuth2%20Walkthrough/IdSrv/Startup.cs#L17

as an example.

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. I am unsure where to do that. I edited my question to show the code I am using.