# How to disabling SSL for identityserver4

Tags: ssl, .net-core, identityserver4

I need to disable SSL/TSL for IdentityServer4 in DotNet Core 2 for test purpose. I have seen this link : [disabling SSL for identityserver3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38247025/disabling-ssl-for-identityserver3) but I need it in version 4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the clue from @Hbert Jarema I was able to find it in the documentation:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
    {
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    });
```

Comment: Inside the ConfigureServices Method in your Startup.cs File.

Comment: This is not working for me! any other configuration has needed?

Answer (score 1):

**The Https can be disabled in the client as well**. 
DiscoveryClient can be found in the assembly IdentityModel (NuGet). I use the following code and it works:

```
    var client = new DiscoveryClient("http://localhost:5000");
    client.Policy.RequireHttps = false;
    var discovery = await client.GetAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `RequireHttpsMetadata` to false in `AddIdentityServerAuthentication` like this:

```
.AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options => {
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false
});
```

Comment: are you sure this is for identityserver4 ?

Comment: The link you provided is nothing to do with RequireHttpsMetadata