# OIDC Connect and Auth Code Flow with PKCE in Angular and Identity Server 4

Tags: angular, openid-connect

I'm using the [angular-auth-oidc-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-auth-oidc-client) package for my Angular application. I've been using it for a long time with Identity Server 3 and it has worked fine when using the Implicit Flow. But when trying to use the Auth Code Flow with PKCE on Identity Server 4, I can't get it to work.

My auth server client is configured like this:

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "My.Angular.App",

    // no interactive user, use the clientid/secret for authentication
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,

    // secret for authentication
    ClientSecrets = new List<Secret> { ... },

    RedirectUris = new List<string> { ... },

    AllowedScopes = new List<string> { ... },
}
```

The configuration for the angular-auth-oidc-client is as follows:

```
{
    "stsServer": "https://auth2.test.hsahealthplan.com",
    "redirect_url": "...",
    "client_id": "My.Angular.app",
    "response_type": "code",
    "scope": "...",
    "post_logout_redirect_uri": "...",
    "start_checksession": false,
    "silent_renew": true,
    "silent_renew_url": "...",
    "post_login_route": "...",
    "forbidden_route": "...",
    "unauthorized_route": "...",
    "log_console_warning_active": true,
    "log_console_debug_active": false,
    "max_id_token_iat_offset_allowed_in_seconds": 300
}
```

When I run Identity Server 4 locally with the `stsServer` set to `https://localhost:5000`:

[image: https local auth server error]

When I run Identity Server 4 locally with the `stsServer` set to `http://localhost:5000`:

[image: http local auth server error]

When I try and authenticate with a real auth server that we have other applications authenticating with:

[image: auth server error response]

I'm not sure why I'm getting an error code of 405 from the auth server, or why it doesn't work locally either. If anyone has any suggestions, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Probably IdentityServer implementation contains CORS middleware (app.UseCors(...)) that conflicts with IdentityServer internal CORS service.
app.UseCors(...) should be called after app.UseIdentityServer in the Startup.Configure

Answer (score 0):

It's logical that the other ID4 server does not accept your request as it does not have your app registered in it. The Client information is not known to that ID4 server and thus it will reject requests coming from your app.

Calling `https://localhost:5000` fails because you misconfigured SSL somewhere, where and how is not clear to me from the information provided. Calling `http://localhost:5000` might be failing [because you forgot to turn off SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47019923/how-to-disabling-ssl-for-identityserver4). It's also possible that CORS is misconfigured, every resource you request from a domain other then the main domain of your app needs to have your domain as a value in the 'access-control-allow-origin' header. So if your app hosted at app.com requests something from ID4.com, the requested resource needs to have app.com in the 'access-control-allow-origin' header.